# How do you experimentally distinguish $\psi_1 \otimes \psi_2$ and $\psi_2 \otimes \psi_1$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-entanglement, quantum-states

What I am asking is that $\psi_1 \otimes  \psi_2$ and $\psi_2 \otimes  \psi_1$ are obviously different states.

However, theoretically a measurement can be done that these to states will give two different eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Staying within single-particle QM for the moment, if $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$ are different states, then there exists an operator $\hat A$ that has at least some nonzero probability of producing different eigenvalues for the two, and which can be used to discriminate between them.

This is a broad area, because of the various ways in which you might want to go about this: does the measurement need to be unambiguous? can you accept a finite probability of failure? are your states orthogonal? and so on. The general problem is known as quantum state discrimination, and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.02571) and [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.1970) look like good reviews. The details of the interpretation do matter, but the take-home message is that there exists an operator $\hat A$ for which (possibly repeated) measurements can be used to distinguish between $\psi_1$ and $\psi_2$.

Now, if you have a two-particle system and you want to distinguish between $\psi_1\otimes \psi_2$ and $\psi_2\otimes \psi_1$, simply perform those same measurements on $\hat A \otimes \hat A$. (Or, heck, just use those same quantum-state-discrimination tools on the pair $\phi_1=\psi_1\otimes \psi_2$ and $\phi_2=\psi_2\otimes \psi_1$.)

You're correct that this isn't broadly discussed in textbooks. That's generally because it's too trivial to be worth the space, I should think.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we're talking about states of two particles, the answer crucially depends on whether the particle are identical (i.e. of the same type or not).

Say we have two different particles: for example, an electron and a proton. Then the two tensor products can be distinguished by looking at which state a specific particle is in. For example, if $\psi_1$ is peaked at a position $\mathbf{r}_1$ and $\psi_2$ at $\mathbf{r}_2$, you simply look near $\mathbf{r}_1$ and see what particle you find there.

But if the particles are identical, this doesn't work! If you have two electrons (or two protons, or two whatevers), then the states $\psi_1 \otimes \psi_2$ and $\psi_2 \otimes \psi_1$ are completely indistinguishable. This means that we shouldn't even use them as states! I'm not going to write down the whole theory of identical particles here, but the upshot is this: we should use states that are the same if we rearrange the order of the particles. "The same" means equal up to a phase, and it can be shown that this phase can be at most a minus sign, so in principle we could have two states:

$$\psi_S = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1 \otimes \psi_2 + \psi_2 \otimes \psi_1)$$
$$\psi_A = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\psi_1 \otimes \psi_2 - \psi_2 \otimes \psi_1)$$

And as it turns out, we are not free to choose. The type of particle determines which one we have to use. Bosons, which have integer spin (so spin 0, spin 1, etc.) use symmetric states. Fermiones, which have half-integer spin, use antisymmetric states.